# what's a shallow copy of a literal result element in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, literals, shallow-copy

regarding:

> A literal result element acts as an
>   instruction to construct an element
>   node with the same name in the result
>   tree. The XSLT processor effectively
>   creates a shallow copy of the literal
>   result element from the stylesheet and
>   inserts it into the result tree at the
>   location within the result tree that
>   is currently being constructed.

Source: http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/#literal_result_elements

I'm wondering what does he mean when he say `The XSLT processor effectively creates a shallow copy of the literal result element` ?

What's a *shallow copy* mean in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering what does he mean when
>   he say`The XSLT processor effectively
>   creates a shallow copy of the literal
>   result element` ?
>
> What's a *shallow copy mean* in this
>   context?

**The [W3C XSLT specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#literal-result-element), which is the only normative document specification of the XSLT language doesn't use the term "shallow copy"**

**My guess** what the material referenced in this question wanted to state, is illustrated by this example:

```
 <h1>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </h1>
```

In the output, the element `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` isn't copied. A "shallow copy" does not copy any children nodes.

**Once again, it is best to forget about "shallow copying" of the literal redult element and to rely only on the normative specification.**

Comment: @Java: The books by @Michael Kay are what I usually recommend -- he covers everything and in depth.

Comment: @Dimitre ok give me an upvote.. i can't even post links or do upvotes until i've got 15 rep (that's really annoying). 15 rep is hard to get when you don't already have at least 15 rep

Comment: Actually the XSLT 2.0 spec does use the term "shallow copy", though only as a section heading, so there's no formal definition of the term. It means "create an element node whose name [and perhaps namespaces, base URI, etc] are the same as those of X, but without copying the children or attributes of X".

Comment: @Michael Kay: Exactly, and saying that a literal-result-element is "shallow-copied" is plain wrong, because its attributes, if specified and not having AVTs  -- are also copied.